# pic16f877A bootloader error

Tags: pic, bootloader

I have installed bootloader into my pic16f877A and now i am trying to write a  program into pic.But after connecting to my computer it gives error as

```
 Connected to \\.\COM1 at 115200
 Searching for PIC ...
 pic sending unknown data:  "K" <>  0h=
 Check baudrate & Start Write while PIC is not sending serial data (e.g. in reset)
 ERROR!
```

I am using tiny bootloader to program pic16f877A.
I have used this blog https://alselectro.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/pic-boot-loaderno-programmer-required-to-fuse-hex-file/#comment-1159 for instructions to install bootloader.
Have checked my connections but not able to understand whats the problem.I also checked my pic16f877A voltages and found that at pin26(Rx) i am getting high voltage(+5) and pin25 (Tx) is zero.
My max232 capacitor connections are same as in the blog.I also wanted to know how can i make sure that bootloader is successfully installed and working fine.
Now i am getting following error:

```
 Connected to \\.\COM1 at 115200
 Searching for PIC ...
 Wait 200 ms
 Rcv:type= 0h=Not found, 
 ERROR!
```

my rs232 connection:

[image]

Comment: And you have the MAX232 chip in there?

Comment: Yes I have max232 and the connections are same as given in the blog